# How can I create group objects by a field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table in my app that has the following fields: room, start_at, title and panel.

I want to query them divided by rooms, for example, so I can have a json just like this:

```
{
  "rooms": {
    "Asia": [{
        "title": "Asia 1",
        "panel": "Asia 1"
    }, {
        "title": "Asia 2",
        "panel": "Asia 2"
    }],
    "Europe": [{
        "title": "Europe 1",
        "panel": "Europe 1"
    }, {
        "title": "Europe 2",
        "panel": "Europe 2"
    }]
  }
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Hey Morris! Can you add the model of your table? I am not sure what `Asia` and `Europe` are

Comment: You've achieved it if that's what you want. If your question pertains to transforming data we have never seen into this, then that's something you'll need to expand on considerably. A simple example of the source data that produces this output would go a long way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `Rails`, it can be performed as following:

```
grouped_rooms = Room.all.group_by(&:room)
grouped_rooms_json = grouped_rooms.transform_values do |room|
  room.as_json(only: [:id, :created_at])
end
{ "rooms" => grouped_rooms_json }
```